# Why does my command shows that there is "No messages were edited here" when i edited a message and tried the command and didnt work discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Whenever I try to snipe an edited message when clearly there was a edited message and use the command, it always sends "No messages were edited here." when it should not do that at all

```
class Snipe(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.client.sniped_messages = {}
        self.client.edit_sniped_messages = {}

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Snipe commands are working')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_messge_edit(self, before, after):
        if before.author.bot:
            return
        self.client.edit_sniped_messages[before.guild.id, before.channel.id] = (
                                                before.content,
                                                after.content,
                                                before.author,
                                                before.channel.name
                                                )


    @commands.command(aliases = ['es'])
    async def editsnipe(self, ctx):
        try:
            before_content, after_content, author, channel_name = self.client.edit_sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id, ctx.channel.id]

            embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**Before:**\n{before_content}\n\n**After:**\n{after_content}", color=0x00FFFF)
            embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Edited in #{channel_name}")

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            await ctx.send("No messages were edited here.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a `try` and `except` statement in your code, it means you are triggering the `except` statement because there was a an exception generated when it attempted the `try` statements. This most likely happens because it does not identify the values for `before_content, after_content, author, channel_name`.

This might happen because your event `async def on_messge_edit(self, before, after):` has a typo and it should be `async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):`.